# URL/Domain remains when clicking on the subpages - WORDPRESS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, url, href

I'm using wordpress for my website.

I entered the href links on the widgets footer but its not working properly only at the homepage.

Can you help me with my website?
The link at the footer section **"services"** **is not working** it is like duplicates the url and it will not refresh or go to the link I entered.

In homepage, the link is working but the other footer page doesn't work. [Here is the link][1].

On different sections the links set have different URLs.
For example the Custom Apparel one when accessed from the home page has - https://opti-advertising.com/offer/#custom link, while if accessed from Contact page it redirects to https://opti-advertising.com/contact/www.opti-advertising.com/offer/?page_id=20#custom.

CODE:

```
<ul style="line-height: 32px;">
    <li><i style="color: #ff0084;" class="icon-layout"></i> <a href="opti-advertising.com/offer/?page_id=20#online_ads">Online Advertising Services</a></li>

<li><i style="color: #ff0084;" class="icon-layout"></i> <a href="www.opti-advertising.com/offer/?page_id=20#printing">Digital & Offset Printing Services</a></li>

<li><i style="color: #ff0084;" class="icon-layout"></i> 
<a href="www.opti-advertising.com/offer/?page_id=20#custom">Custom Apparel</a></li>

<li><i style="color: #ff0084;" class="icon-layout"></i> 
<a href="www.opti-advertising.com/offer/?page_id=20#traditional">Traditional Advertising Services</a>
</li>

<li><i style="color: #ff0084;" class="icon-layout"></i>
<a href="www.opti-advertising.com/offer/?page_id=20#marketing">Marketing Giveaways</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Where is the code? There are inbuilt permalink generating functions in wordpress use them instead of hardcoding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just hardcoding the links in your footer, e.g. placing links to the footer like this:

```
<a href="www.opti-advertising.com/offer/?page_id=20#printing">Link</a>
```

When you access this link from homepage, CMS serves it from the root of your site, and you get the right address:

```
www.opti-advertising.com/offer/?page_id=20#printing
```

But if you click this link from any secondary page, you will get the address like this:

```
www.opti-advertising.com/page/www.opti-advertising.com/offer/?page_id=20#printing
```

because CMS serves the link from current page, which has path of

```
www.opti-advertising.com/page/
```

To solve this, you should at least remove domain name from the url and prepend a slash to it:

```
<a href="/offer/?page_id=20#printing">Link</a>
```

But the best approach – is to do things right – generate links dynamically. Wordpress gives you some snippets, for example

```
site_url();
```

With this you can do things like:

```
<a href="<?php site_url('/offer/?page_id=20#printing', https); ?>">Link</a>
```

which will on any page output this:

```
https://www.opti-advertising.com/offer/?page_id=20#printing
```

Comment: I've tried to contact my hosting technical team in siteground about the issue. They told  me that "this issue is hardcoded into the theme" and nothing happen. I know that it's not. I use only the first method and it worked. Thank you for solving my problem.